# Setup TeamCity permissions for new projects only

Tags: permissions, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there any possibility to assign role "project administrator" for project creator? 
Now, if you add permission "create project", after creating a project you still can't view/edit it.

My main aim is to create a specific permission that allows a user to create projects and gives "project administrator" for those, but not to view/edit others' projects by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-11157
In brief, this should work if your project creator also has project administrator role in at least one project. In this case, he/she should get project admin role assigned specifically for the newly created project.